# Password box is showing even when the user has no password

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 pro.

Suddenly yesterday , when starting windows , the logon screen is displayed asking me to enter a password for my user.

But my user has no password. So I leave the password box empty and I click the button and the Windows is open.

But every time I start windows  , the password box is showing ( before yesterday the login process was automatic now I should always click the button leaving the password box empty of course )

What can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: Try adding a password then removing it again. Or adding a password and keeping one because that's recommended by the whole internet :P

Comment: I have already done that. But after removing the password , the password box is still showing. I don't want to keep a password. I'm asking why the password box is showing when I have no password ?

Comment: Press WIN + R and enter `netplwiz` into the run prompt, then press ok. Then deselect the box that says "Users must enter a password".

Comment: You have an extremely secure computer.  People will see the password box and assume one is needed.  They will spend forever trying to brute force it.

Comment: @Ramhound You didn't understand my question at all. Can you read on my question ::"...But my user has no password". So windows show password box for an user that doesn't have a password. Now did you understand ? Go and give me another down vote!!!

Comment: @Ramhound This is not an answer.If you read again , I've already done that. Your response doesn't resolve the problem ( I DON'T WANT THE PASSWORD BOX ) but just ignore it. So if I ask you that I have pain when I'm eating , your response may be : DON'T EAT !!!  But at least , you agree that you did not understand my question , so you've given a wrong down vote !

Comment: You have to set default user account in order to skip the login screen.

Comment: @Ramhound I've not changed anything. If you can read my question . One day everything was ok .I turn off the Pc. Next day the password box appearing.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Then type `netplwiz`, deselect "Users must enter a password", press enter and restart the computer.

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hah! I commented this before you answered. But you actually can't just run that you need to deselect "Users must enter a password". The answer is incomplete :P

Comment: Doesn't work , the password box is still showing

Comment: I don't understand those who down voted the question. If you don't like the question , before try to respond and after you can down vote.

Comment: I will fix the answer, please upvote my answer at least.

Comment: Doesn't work. The password box is still showing.

Comment: @jo99blackops  Doesn't work. The password box is still showing.